# Python: how to color the nodes of a network according to their degree?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, networkx

I have a scale-free network made of `10000` nodes, but the texture of edges and the number of nodes make it too intricate to be made sense of. *I want to be able to visually locate the most highly connected nodes.*

**How could I color the nodes based on their degree k?** Specifically, I would like to color them based on pre-assigned ranges, such as:

- Green if `1<k<10`;
- Light blue if `11<k<20`;
- Blue if `21<k<30`;
- Purple if `31<k<40`;
- ...

Here is how I obtain the network:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 10000  # Number of nodes
m = 3  # Number of initial links
seed = 500
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n, m, seed)
ncols = 100
pos = {i : (i % ncols, (n-i-1)//ncols) for i in G.nodes()}
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=False, ax=ax, node_size=10)
degrees=G.degree() #Dict with Node ID, Degree
sum_of_degrees=sum(degrees.values()) #Sum of degrees
avg_degree_unaltered=sum_of_degrees/10000 #The average degree <k>
short_path=nx.average_shortest_path_length(G)
print('seed: '+str(seed)+', short path: '+str(round(short_path,3))+', log(N)=4')
#Plot the graph
plt.xlim(-20,120,10)
plt.xticks(numpy.arange(-20, 130, 20.0))
plt.ylim(120,-20,10) 
plt.yticks(numpy.arange(-20, 130, 20.0))
plt.axis('on')
title_string=('Scale-Free Network') 
subtitle_string=('100x100'+' = '+str(n)+' nodes')
plt.suptitle(title_string, y=0.99, fontsize=17)
plt.title(subtitle_string, fontsize=8)
plt.show()
```

This is the result without applying the differential coloring. **PS:** the initial node with ID 0 is in the top left corner.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the hood this is just implemented as a matplotlib `scatter` plot and the networkx API lets you pass many [options through](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 10000  # Number of nodes
m = 3  # Number of initial links
seed = 500
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n, m, seed)

ncols = 100
pos = {i : (i % ncols, (n-i-1)//ncols) for i in G.nodes()}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
degrees = G.degree() #Dict with Node ID, Degree
nodes = G.nodes()
n_color = np.asarray([degrees[n] for n in nodes])
sc = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=nodes, node_color=n_color, cmap='viridis',
                            with_labels=False, ax=ax, node_size=n_color)
# use a log-norm, do not see how to pass this through nx API
# just set it after-the-fact
sc.set_norm(mcolors.LogNorm())
fig.colorbar(sc)
```

[image: Example output of graph]

This scales both the color and the size based on the degree.

This can be extended using `BoundryNorm` and a discrete color map to segment the nodes into bands.

Comment: Please check my edited image. I've always had problems with this. In my network, the node with ID "0" is in the top left corner, while in yours it is in the bottom left. This has an effect on how the "heatmap" is displayed as this network is generated via *growth* and *preferential attachment* beginning from the upper row. How to change this in your plot?

Comment: There is a `ax.invert_yaxis()` method which will flip the 0 to the top left.  Where the nodes are placed is set by `pos` which you can define anyway you want.  Ex, use `{i : (i % ncols, i//ncols for i in G.nodes()}` to put the biggest nodes near (0, 0) instead of (0, 100).

Comment: I like the `viridis` color scheme but my matplotlib 1.5 does not recognize it. How to include it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to do just 3 colors: green if k<10;  blue if 10<=k <20; orange if 20<=k

```
greennodes = [node for node in G.nodes_iter() if G.degree(node)<10]
bluenodes = [node for node in G.nodes_iter() if 10<=G.degree(node)<20]
orangenodes = [node for node in G.nodes_iter() if 20<= G.degree(node)]

pos = {i : (i % ncols, (n-i-1)//ncols) for i in G.nodes()}
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos) #draw edges first
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, with_labels=False, ax=ax, node_size=10, nodelist = 
greennodes, node_color = 'g') #draw green nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, with_labels=False, ax=ax, node_size=10, nodelist = 
bluenodes, node_color = 'g') #draw blue nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, with_labels=False, ax=ax, node_size=10, nodelist = 
orangenodes, node_color = 'g') #draw orange nodes
```

probably a nicer way (with itertools?) to avoid having to loop through the nodes 3 times to collect them all.