# how can we color node which has many connections, which have few connections and which have no connections?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

In this image you can see three types of nodes, I want to color the  first  type node  which has many connections and high degree.
[image: In this images you can see three types of nodes, I want to color the first type node which has many connections and high degree]

```
import pandas as pd

import networkx as nx

import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("F:/2004-2019/sam.csv")
df

    Source  Target  weight
0   AA  AA  12
1   AA  AB  10
2   AA  AC  10
3   AA  AD  9
4   AA  AE  8
5   AA  AF  7
6   AA  AG  6
7   AA  AH  2
8   AA  AI  2
9   AA  AJ  2
10  AA  AK  2
11  AA  AL  2
12  AA  AM  2
13  AA  AN  2
14  AA  AO  2
15  AA  AP  2
16  AA  AQ  2
17  AA  AR  2
18  AA  AS  2
19  AB  BB  2
20  AB  BC  2
21  AB  BD  2
22  AB  BE  2
23  AB  BF  2
24  AB  BG  2
25  AB  BH  2
26  AC  CC  2
27  AC  CD  2
28  AC  CE  2
29  AC  CF  2
30  AC  CG  2
31  AC  CH  2
32  AC  CI  2
33  AD  DD  2
34  AD  DE  2
35  AD  DF  2
36  AD  DG  2
37  AD  DH  2

graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Source',target='Target')

graph.nodes()

NodeView(('AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'CC', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'DD', 'DE', 'DF', 'DG', 'DH'))

graph.edges()
EdgeView([('AA', 'AA'), ('AA', 'AB'), ('AA', 'AC'), ('AA', 'AD'), ('AA', 'AE'), ('AA', 'AF'), ('AA', 'AG'), ('AA', 'AH'), ('AA', 'AI'), ('AA', 'AJ'), ('AA', 'AK'), ('AA', 'AL'), ('AA', 'AM'), ('AA', 'AN'), ('AA', 'AO'), ('AA', 'AP'), ('AA', 'AQ'), ('AA', 'AR'), ('AA', 'AS'), ('AB', 'BB'), ('AB', 'BC'), ('AB', 'BD'), ('AB', 'BE'), ('AB', 'BF'), ('AB', 'BG'), ('AB', 'BH'), ('AC', 'CC'), ('AC', 'CD'), ('AC', 'CE'), ('AC', 'CF'), ('AC', 'CG'), ('AC', 'CH'), ('AC', 'CI'), ('AD', 'DD'), ('AD', 'DE'), ('AD', 'DF'), ('AD', 'DG'), ('AD', 'DH')])

g1 = list (df.Source.unique())
```

g1

```
['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD']

g2 = list(df.Target.unique())
```

g2

```
['AA',
'AB',
 'AC',
 'AD',
 'AE',
 'AF',
 'AG',
 'AH',
 'AI',
 'AJ',
 'AK',
 'AL',
 'AM',
 'AN',
 'AO',
 'AP',
 'AQ',
 'AR',
 'AS',
 'BB',
 'BC',
 'BD',
 'BE',
 'BF',
 'BG',
 'BH',
 'CC',
 'CD',
 'CE',
 'CF',
 'CG',
 'CH',
 'CI',
 'DD',
 'DE',
 'DF',
 'DG',
 'DH']

wt= list(df.weight)
```

wt

```
[12,
10,
 10,
 9,
 8,
 7,
 6,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2]

dict(zip(g1, g2))
{'AA': 'AA', 'AB': 'AB', 'AC': 'AC', 'AD': 'AD'}

graph.degree('AA')
20

[a for a in g1]
['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD']

[graph.degree(a) for a in g1]
[20, 8, 8, 6]

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))

graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Source', target='Target') 
 
layout = nx.spring_layout(graph,iterations=50)

AA_size = [graph.degree(a) * 80 for a in g1]

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, 
                       layout, 
                       nodelist=g1, 
                       node_size=AA_size,
                       node_color='red')

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, layout, nodelist=g2, node_color='#e8af05', node_size=100)

popular_AA = [a1 for a1 in g2 if graph.degree(a1) > 1]

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, layout, nodelist=popular_AA, node_color='red', node_size=100)


nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, layout, width=wt,
        with_labels=True, edge_color="#1a7800")

node_labels = dict(zip(g1, g2))

nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, layout, labels=node_labels)

plt.axis('off')
```

It's a networkx data. I have been trying to plot the network graph which will represent three types of networks, i.e, three type nodes with three colors. Actually, there should be three types of nodes, I colored two types, unable to color the 1st type (AA). can any help

Comment: `node_labels = dict(zip(g1, g2))` sounds really wrong. What defines the second type nodes here?

Comment: sorry for the incorrect info i gave! actually, I colored which have few connections and which have no connections. i want to give separate color to one node which has high connections and high degree.

Comment: So you want to [color nodes by degree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782251/python-how-to-color-the-nodes-of-a-network-according-to-their-degree)?

Comment: Actually I have increased the size of nodes by degree *80.  And I have colored the nodes based on degree! As you can see in the image I have colored the nodes which have no degree and which have degree > 1. I just want to color the one node which has high degree, large in size. Which will represent that it has many connections. Thank you.